# How to find the probability that the permutation does not have adjacent digits?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

I am learning how to use exclusion-inclusion principle (PIE). I wish to find the probability that a random permutation of $1112345$ does not have adjacent digits like for example $1121345$ and $2345111$ are not allowed.

There are $\frac{7!}{3!}=840$ possible permutations.

I think the probability can be calculated using the principle of inclusion-exclusion:

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{does not have adjacent 1s})&=1-P(\text{have at least a pair of adjacent 1s})
\\&=
1-P(\text{have sequence 11 OR have sequence 111})
\\&=
1-(P(\text{have sequence 11})+P(\text{have sequence 111})-P(\text{have sequence 11 AND have sequence 111}))
\end{align}
$$

Is that the correct application of PIE?

I know how to calculate $P(\text{have sequence 11})$ and $P(\text{have sequence 11})$ but I am not sure how to calculate $P(\text{have sequence 11 AND have sequence 111})$.

Comment: It looks like you meant to say that a permutation does not have adjacent identical digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a correct application of P.I.E., but not a useful one. The problem is that if your permutation contains $111$, it certainly also contains $11$. So you end up simplifying to $1 - P(\text{has }11) + P(\text{has }111) - P(\text{has }111)$ or just $1 - P(\text{has }11)$, which is what you started with.

A more profitable approach is to label the $1$'s to distinguish them: $1_a 1_b 1_c 2345$. Then do inclusion/exclusion on the three events "$1_a$ and $1_b$ are adjacent", "$1_b$ and $1_c$ are adjacent", and "$1_a$ and $1_c$ are adjacent".

Call these events $A_{ab}, A_{bc}, A_{ac}$ respectively. Then we want to find
\begin{align}
P(\text{no adjacent 1's}) &= 1 - P(A_{ab} \text{ or } A_{bc} \text{ or } A_c) \\
&= 1 - P(A_{ab}) - P(A_{bc}) - P(A_{ac}) \\
& \quad + P(A_{ab} \text{ and } A_{bc}) + P(A_{ab} \text{ and } A_{bc})  + P(A_{ac} \text{ and } A_{bc}) \\
& \quad - P(A_{ab} \text{ and } A_{bc} \text{ and } A_{ac}) \\
&= 1 - 3 P(A_{ab}) + 3 P(A_{ab} \text{ and } A_{bc})
\end{align}
where the last line follows by symmetry (plus the fact that $1_a, 1_b, 1_c$ cannot *all* be adjacent to each other).

Here, $P(A_{ab}) = \frac{2 \cdot 6!}{7!} = \frac27$: if $1_a$ and $1_b$ are adjacent, we can treat them as one symbol $[1_a 1_b]$, so there are $6!$ ways to order the $6$ symbols we now have, and then $2$ ways to choose the order of $1_a$ and $1_b$. We can compute $P(A_{ab} \text{ and }A_{bc})$ similarly.

Comment: Thank you but I am bit confused about your $P(A_{ab})$ calculation. I also treated $[1_a 1_b]$ as a symbol and I thought the probability is $\frac{6!}{\frac{7!}{3!}}=\frac{6}{7}$? To calculate $P(A_{ab} \text{ and }A_{bc})$, I need to treat $[1_a 1_b 1_c]$ as a symbol right?

Comment: (1) We no longer divide by $7!/3!$ but by $7!$, since we distinguish $1_a$, $1_b$, and $1_c$. Also, don't forget that the symbol $[1_a 1_b]$ can be turned back into $1_a 1_b$ or into $1_b 1_a$, hence the factor of $2$. (2) Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This is odd... I found out that $P(E_{ab} \text{ and } E_{bc})=\frac{3!5!}{7!}=\frac17$ and the final answer is $P(\text{no adjacent 1s}) = 1 - 3 \frac27 + 3 \frac17 = \frac47$ but the other answer gives $\frac27$. I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: $P(E_{ab} \text{ and } E_{bc})$ is not $\frac{3!5!}{7!}$ but $\frac{2!5!}{7!}$.

Comment: But there are $3!=6$ ways to order $[1_a 1_b 1_c]$?

Comment: But only $1_a 1_b 1_c$ and $1_c 1_b 1_a$ make both $E_{ab}$ and $E_{bc}$ happen.

Comment: Oh right, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

Use **Stars and Bars** theory.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The $3$ 1's divide the sequence into $4$ regions.

Consider the number of solutions to :

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4.$
- $x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

The 3rd bullet point above accommodates that none of the 1's can be adjacent to each other.

If $S$ is the number of solutions, then the probability will be

$$\frac{4! \times S}{D} ~: ~D = \frac{7!}{3!} = 840.$$

This is because for each satisfying solution, there are $4!$ ways of ordering the digits that are not equal to $1$.

---

$S$ may be readily computed via a change of variable.

Let $~y_2 = x_2 - 1, ~y_3 = x_3 - 1.$

Then the computation of $S$ corresponds to the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + x_4 = 4 - 2 = 2.$
- $x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2, y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory,

$$S = \binom{2 + 3}{3} = \binom{5}{3} = 10 \implies $$

the corresponding probability equals

$$\frac{10 \times 4!}{840} = \frac{2}{7}.$$